# Do association bonuses stack?

Tags: support, reputation, stackexchange

If a user gets 200 rep on one stack receives their bonus on a second stack and they then get 200 rep on a third stack, Does the user receive another rep bonus or does it only happen once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Association bonus is a one-time bonus. If you've received it once, you won't get it again.

Comment: It's once per site, though, so if you create an account on a site after you have 200 rep somewhere already, you'll start with 101 rep thanks to the bonus.